# Change RDS Configuration in Elastic Beanstalk App?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I want to change my RDS Instance that is connected to my Elastic Beanstalk Application, from a db.t1.micro to a db.m1.small. If I go to my Elastic Beanstalk Application and go to "Configuration", I can only see the current settings, but I'm unable to change them.

I then went into the Console -> RDS -> Instances, and updated my Instance from the RDS Menu, and set it as a db.m1.small. On RDS it now says that it's an db.m1.small, however on the Elastic Beanstalk Configuration Page, it still says that the application is running a db.t1.micro instance.

So a few questions:

- Did I upgrade my instance in the "correct" way? Or is there another way I'm suppose to configure my RDS Instance that is set up with my Elastic Beanstalk App?
- Any ideas why the different pages are saying different configurations?

Answer (score 3):

If RDS console says that the RDS instance type is m1.small then it has been changed to m1.small. The two pages are showing different values because beanstalk provisioned a t1.micro instance instance for you and hence thinks you have a t1.micro db instance. If you rebuild your environment then the new environment should have the same configuration and hence a t1.micro instance.
Changing it via the RDS console does not change the configuration on Beanstalk, hence you see different values.

However if the RDS instance was created via Beanstalk then the correct way to update your db instance type would be using Elastic Beanstalk option settings.

You can make the change using AWS CLI if not using the console.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/

Just run the following command:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk --update-environment --environment-name <your-env-name> --option-settings Namespace=aws:rds:dbinstance,OptionName=DBInstanceClass,Value=db.m1.small
```

Try the above command.
More information on update-environment via aws cli:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/update-environment.html

Read more about option settings and ebextensions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html).

Comment: It looks like you can now change the instance class directly in the Beanstalk UI. However there is still a lot that you cannot change e.g. backup retention. I'm wondering if it would provide greater flexibility (for those who prefer to work in the UI) to manually create the RDS instance, then attach it to Beanstalk.

Comment: Hmm, guess you can't attach directly to Beanstalk, and maybe you don't want to: http://serverfault.com/questions/540828/how-to-associate-an-existing-rds-instance-to-an-elastic-beanstalk-environment/